# Border multiple lines of text as a block within more text

Tags: javascript, html, css, coding-style

I'm trying to set a border around multiple lines of text within a paragraph. I basically don't want the border to appear on each line, but around all the lines.

I realize I could wrap all the text in a div, but then it blocks that text from the rest of the paragraph.

I want a fluid paragraph and for one sentence over multiple lines to have a top border, side borders for the length of the lines, and a bottom border, and for that border to end at the end of the sentence and before the next sentence begins.

Like so:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that there is an easy solution for this. You could try to segment the words into several `<span>` parts and then calculate for every `<span>` the required borders.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a try to imbricate 2 inline elements

- inline parent : give an `outline`
- inline child : give `position`, a `background` and eventually a `box-shadow` to fill the gap in between 2 lines (if any)

```css
b {
  outline:solid red;
}
span {
  position:relative;
  background:white;box-shadow:0 0 0 1px white;
}
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, <b><span>tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui.</span></b> Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
```

If you want straight lines on both sides, give a try to `text-align`:

```css
p {
text-align:justify
}
b {
  outline:solid red;
}
span {
  position:relative;
  background:white;box-shadow:0 0 0 1px white;
}
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, <b><span>tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui.</span></b> Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
```

here is a pen to play with : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dWPGXv

Comment: Sweet, this is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @JonathanWexler Please remember to accept the answer if it solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do this as well. This is as close as I've gotten so far:

```css
div{
  font:500 12px/14px arial;
}
p{
  display:inline;
  background:#ff0000;
  padding:0 1px;
}
.whitepad{
  background:#ffffff;
  vertical-align:top;
  border:1px solid #ffffff;
  padding:1px 0 0;
  margin:0 -1px;
}
.redpad{
  position:relative;
  top:1px;
  left:1px;
  background:#ffffff;
  margin:0px 3px 0px 1px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span class="whitepad">This is some text that's not outlined</span><span class="redpad">and this is some text that is totally outlined in red like you want. Seek and thou shalt find. Listen and thou shalt hear. I don't know I'm making up text. It needs to be super long text in order to accomplish the thing for testing. Even longer than this. it needs to keep getting longer. Okay that's good. Total props to me </span><span class="whitepad">and then this is again not outlined</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

I will try to refine this, just wanted to leave it here for others to see.

Comment: @JonathanWexler Yes his answer was superb. I'm using it and upvoted him lol. Hopefully this snippet can help someone out in the future though